# LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'. when I tried running a program using Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, admin

I was trying to run a python program on my computer, the command I use is
py -3 manage.py runserver,
but I ran into an error and I couldn't find any helpful posts online that can solve this problem.

Python version is Python 3.7.3
Django version is 2.2

Here is the error message:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Intern\Diversity_Policy_Site\blog\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .search import PolicyIndex
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Intern\Diversity_Policy_Site\blog\search.py", line 14, in <module>
    connections.create_connection(hosts=["https://dd90577b842c4f9396ca1846612e98df.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9243"], http_auth=('elastic', 'Mq2jdfPLSRG1m8qxp4vd0qNa'))
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch_dsl\connections.py", line 66, in create_connection
    conn = self._conns[alias] = Elasticsearch(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\__init__.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.transport = transport_class(_normalize_hosts(hosts), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\transport.py", line 108, in __init__
    self.set_connections(hosts)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\transport.py", line 157, in set_connections
    connections = list(zip(connections, hosts))
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\transport.py", line 154, in _create_connection
    return self.connection_class(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 161, in __init__
    "Root certificates are missing for certificate "
elasticsearch.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Root certificates are missing for certificate validation. Either pass them in using the ca_certs parameter or install certifi to use it automatically.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 155, in get_app_config
    return self.app_configs[app_label]
KeyError: 'admin'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 579, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 564, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 272, in run
    get_resolver().urlconf_module
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 564, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Intern\Diversity_Policy_Site\mysite\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 256, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 529, in _setup
    AdminSiteClass = import_string(apps.get_app_config('admin').default_site)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 162, in get_app_config
    raise LookupError(message)
LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'.
```

The above code is the error I have, the posts I found online were not helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565665/no-installed-app-with-label-admin-running-django-migration-the-app-is-insta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565665/no-installed-app-with-label-admin-running-django-migration-the-app-is-insta) maybe?

Comment: Your problem is in this line with posiible ways to handle it - `elasticsearch.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Root certificates are missing for certificate validation. Either pass them in using the ca_certs parameter or install certifi to use it automatically.`

Comment: @Bidhan Majhi Thanks for pointing that out, I just installed certifi, and the error didn't how up. Even though there is a new error, the one above is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type this command in cmd:

```
pip install certifi
```

and the above error should be solved.